# Microsoft OAuth not configured as a multi-tenant app and usage of common endpoint not supported, but needs to be single-tenant

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth

I'm using Microsoft OAuth authentication in an ASP.NET 7 web app

Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
{
    microsoftOptions.ClientId = configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientId"];
    microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientSecret"];
});
```

and getting the error message

`AADSTS50194: Application 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' is not configured as a multi-tenant application. Usage of the /common endpoint is not supported for such applications created after '10/15/2018'. Use a tenant-specific endpoint or configure the application to be multi-tenant.`

However, I'm not trying to make a multi-tenant app, but rather a single-tenant app. How do I configure the endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/19795), if you're using an app with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount`, Microsoft Account OAuth provider's default uses a common endpoint:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
```

This is assumed to be a *multitenant* app and has the permission level "Accounts in any organizational directory".

If you want a single tenant app, then you have to specify the authorization and token endpoint in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
{
    microsoftOptions.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/YOUR_TENANT_ID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize";
    microsoftOptions.TokenEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/YOUR_TENANT_ID/oauth2/v2.0/token";
    microsoftOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientId"];
    microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientSecret"];
});
```

The URLs for the endpoints can be found in the *Endpoints* tab of the *App Registration* overview page on Azure, and the OAuth 2.0 authorization endpoint and token endpoint will have your tenant ID already in the URL.

[Documentation on the `MicrosoftAccountOptions`.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.microsoftaccount.microsoftaccountoptions?view=aspnetcore-6.0)